# Connecting CSS and JSS to HTML on the WSGI client

Tags: javascript, css, server, wsgi, content-type

I have the following code that implements page routing on the waitress server. I am faced with the following task: I need to connect CSS and JS styles, how do I do this?

```
from waitress import serve

def render_template(template_name, context={}):
   html_str=""
   with open(template_name, 'r') as f:
       html_str=f.read()
       html_str=html_str.format(**context)
   return html_str

def home(environ):
   return render_template('templates/index.html', context={})

def contact_us(environ):
   return render_template('templates/contact.html', context={})

def contact2(environ):
   return render_template('templates/2.html', context={})

def app(environ, start_response):
   path= environ.get("PATH_INFO")
   if path == "/":
     page = home(environ)
   elif path == "/contact":
     page = contact_us(environ)
   elif path == "/contact/2":
     page = contact2(environ)
   else:
     page = render_template('templates/404.html', context={"path":path})
  page = page.encode("utf-8")

  start_response(
    f"200 OK", [
        ("Content-type", "text/html"),
     ]
   )
  return iter([page])
serve(app)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding thiscondition, the app checks if the requested path starts with "/static/". If it does, it attempts to serve the static file directly from the specified path. This way, your CSS and JS files will be served correctly.

```
          if path.startswith("/static/"):
                    # Serve static files directly
                    static_file_path = path.lstrip("/static/")
                    try:
                        with open(static_file_path, 'rb') as f:
                            content = f.read()
                        start_response("200 OK", [("Content-type", "text/css" if path.endswith(".css") else "text/javascript")])
                        return [content]
                    except FileNotFoundError:
                        start_response("404 Not Found", [("Content-type", "text/plain")])
                        return [b"404 Not Found"]
```

Comment: Please tell me what the architecture of the project should be?

Comment: Project Structure:my_web_app/
├── app.py            # WSGI application code
├── templates/        # HTML templates
├── static/           # Static files (CSS and JS)
├── server.py         # Waitress server configuration
└── requirements.txt  # List of dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ramziya's answer, I figured out how to do it, for which many thanks!
So far I've only connected CSS styles, but I already know how to do it with JS, I'll do it later!

```
from waitress import serve

def render_template(template_name, context={}):
 html_str=""
 with open(template_name, 'r') as f:
    html_str=f.read()
    html_str=html_str.format(**context)
 return html_str

def home(environ):
 return render_template('templates/index.html', context={})

def contact_us(environ):
 return render_template('templates/contact.html', context={})

def contact2(environ):
 return render_template('templates/2.html', context={})

def app(environ, start_response):
 path= environ.get("PATH_INFO")
 if path.startswith("/src/css/"):
    new_path = path.replace('/','',1)
    try:
        with open(new_path, 'rb') as f:
            content = f.read()
        start_response("200 OK", [("Content-type", "text/css")])
        return [content]
    except FileNotFoundError:
        start_response("404 Not Found", [("Content-type", "text/plain")])
        return [b"404 Not Found css/js"]
    

 if path == "/":
     page = home(environ)
 elif path == "/contact":
     page = contact_us(environ)
 elif path == "/contact/2":
     page = contact2(environ)
 else:
     page = render_template('templates/404.html', context={"path":path})
 page = page.encode("utf-8")

 start_response(
     f"200 OK", [
         ("Content-type", "text/html"),
     ]
 )
 return iter([page])

serve(app)
```